# How to make a VSE scene strip render with the openGL render?

Tags: rendering, video-sequence-editor, opengl

Is it possible to have a scene strip in the VSE render using the OpenGL renderer?

I know you can make it render using viewport shading/OpenGL in the preview, but can you do this for the final render, without first rendering to an image sequence and loading that back into the VSE?

I have a couple scene strips, one is a a cycles scene, and the other is some text objects and stuff to be overlayed on the cycles render. I would like to render the text with OpenGL as it's just flat shading, and cycles is overkill.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Blender 2.76 or later you can render a Scene Strip in the VSE using OpenGL by hitting one of the two Buttons next to "Use Backdrop". The left one will render a single frame, the right one the entire animation.

[image: Screenshot of OpenGL Buttons]

In case you want to have transparency for the VSE OpenGL render, it seems you have to set the alpha mode of the OpenGL render options to transparent **before** adding the scene to the VSE when using 2.79 (Render -> OpenGL Render Options -> Alpha Mode -> Transparent).

Comment: i have a simple default cube in the scene, but when i import the scene in the vse layer on top of my video clip , the cube appears but the background in not transparent, it is the world background (grey), how do i make the background transparent so that the bottom layer is visible below the cube?

Comment: @vikrant I edited the answer with information on how to get Alpha working.

Comment: thanks for the edit, in addition to this i think we also have to make the world background transparent, i did this by using node editor, just slide the alpha all the way to left and set alpha mode to transparent as you suggested.

Answer (score 2):

No - openGL rendering is a simple representation of the 3dview only available from the 3dview. It is basically a screen capture of the 3D viewport.

But you can save an opengl render of the scene and add the image/video files to the vse, or set the text scene to BI with simple shading to get a fast render.

Even using cycles for a text only render you only need a diffuse node and 1 sample to get a sub-second per frame render, turn off shadows and caustics to ensure the fastest result.

Comment: I'd opt for second solution, but with an emission shader (if text is colored) or a holdout shader (if it's black)

Comment: With only one sample you get no AA though..