# Video in blender has audio out of sync regardless of fps settings

Tags: video

As the title says I am having trouble getting a video to be in sync with the audio.

The footage was captured from my computer at 60fps and i can confirm this via VLC player, also the footage as viewed through VLC player is all in sync with the audio. Where the problem arises is as soon as i put it into blenders sequencer, where the audio will be occurring up to 2 seconds infront of the video (2 seconds out of sync that is).

I have tried changing fps settings before importing the video but to no avail, i have AV-sync turned on to rule out the fact that its drifting over time. It seems that it is out of sync as soon as i start the video regardless of how long its playing, even on a 20 second video clip the audio is out of sync from beginning to end (but starts and ends at the exact same frame as the video).

Some advice would be greatly appreciated as i am trying to develop  my video editing skills but this is really making it hard and I'm at a lost end with it after trying for hours to figure it out by myself.

Thanks in advance, Sam.

Comment: does it render out of sync ?

Comment: Maybe the OpenGL Render option might help here? See http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15440/how-to-make-a-vse-scene-strip-render-with-the-opengl-render

Comment: Yes it renders out of sync as well as the preview is out of sync before rendering, I will give OpenGL a go, thanks