# Quickly resize a picture in Video Sequence Editor

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I am having lot's of troubles to do a very simple thing. I just would like to (fully) display a picture whose size is bigger than the initial canvas. Indeed, when you add a new picture, it is resized so that it fits the whole canvas, even if it breaks the scale. Then if I want to recover the scale, I can try do two things :

- Add a transform layer on top of the current layer, and apply some rescale on the y axis only. Actually, it works, but it nothing but practical ! Most of the time I need to open a calculatrice, find the size of the image, the size of the canvas, and manually compute the needed y ratio... Crazy !
- The second option (which is fact does not work) is to check the box "Image Offset" in order to recover the original scale, and then to scale down directly in the "scale" menu on the right without applying any transform layer... But the problem is that the picture is cut (crop): anything that was originally outside of the canvas just disappear, so only a part of the picture is visible...

When is the good way to insert a picture whose size is bigger than the canvas ?

Thank you.

Comment: You cannot do this with VSE, try the compositor, add a scene and resize there. Then bring that scene back into VSE scene as a scene strip. It renders a bit slower but much quicker than rendering a plane in 3D view. Unless you use OpenGL render ;-)

Comment: Thank you, it works indeed... The major problem of that method is that the VSE preview is slower : instead of displaying 24 fps, it displays now 7 fps... It's not possible to "cache" the result to avoid this problem ?

Comment: IF you play that section back in non sync mode then all frames will be rendered to a buffer. But its temporary and you can max out the buffer. Otherwise you must render it out. Sadly the OpenGL 3D view is preferable as it can be real time, but is not a core renderer yet so it isn't easily available to the VSE.

Comment: Do you know how it would be possible to add the OpenGL 3D view in VSE ?

Comment: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15440/how-to-make-a-vse-scene-strip-render-with-the-opengl-render try this for a start